# SQLite3 Import data as datetime format

Tags: sqlite

### Objective

Import my date column data into my sqlite3 table as datetime

### Issue

From what I've read online it appears one needs to convert "date" data into `datetime` when importing into `sqlite3` as the only options of data types are `text`,`integer`,`blob` and `real`. I've had a review and tried to work the `strftime` command - which I understand should be able to convert this - but from what I've seen online people refer to it within an sql query as opposed to an import. Can someone confirm if what I am doing is correct or what I'm doing wrong with how I should `CAST` the date input? Sorry if this is a basic question, it's my first time trying to build my own sql tables with data.

### Notes

I am aware that the `CAST` line for my date column throws out errors as it expects the `AS` command.

### Script

```
sqlite3 -batch ~/.databases/mydatabase.db <<EOF
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydata(
Client  TEXT NOT NULL,
Date    TEXT NOT NULL,
Platform        TEXT,

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE data(
Client  TEXT NOT NULL,
Date    INTEGER NOT NULL,
Platform        TEXT,

.mode tabs
.separator \t
.import tabledata.tsv data

INSERT INTO mydata_data (Client, Date, Platform)

SELECT                                                                                                                   
    CAST (Client AS TEXT),                                                                                               
    CAST (strftime('%Y-%m-%d',Date)),
    CAST (Platform AS TEXT)
FROM data;
EOF
```

### Date format

```
2020-03-19
2020-03-07
2020-03-20
2020-03-08
2020-03-04
2020-03-21
2020-03-22
2020-02-22
2020-02-24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I don't know how to read documentation and there is a `Date` data type for `sqlite3`

```
sqlite3 -batch ~/.databases/mydatabase.db <<EOF
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydata(
    Client  TEXT NOT NULL,
    Date    DATE NOT NULL,
    Platform        TEXT,

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE data(
    Client  TEXT NOT NULL,
    Date    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Platform        TEXT,

    .mode tabs
    .separator \t
    .import tabledata.tsv data

    INSERT INTO mydata_data (Client, Date, Platform)

    SELECT                                                                                                                   
        CAST (Client AS TEXT),                                                                                               
        strftime('%Y-%m-%d',Date),
        CAST (Platform AS TEXT)
    FROM data;
    EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks ok, but depending on what you want to do with the data you can also keep the dates as timestamps. If you primarily use the `Date` column to display a date without reformatting then do what you do, it works. However, if primarily use the `Date` column in date calculations, or format it to different locales before displaying it, you can keep it as a number too, you can always use `strftime` in queries to format the numerical representation to whatever locale representation you want at query time.

Comment: my aim was to query date ranges with the column and hoped this could be imported correctly so I didn't have to remember the `strftime`. Is that possible or do I have to focus on doing so in the query itself? In which case are you advising to keep it as an integer as opposed to a string - based on how I will use the column?

Comment: If your primary use case is to select date ranges I think your queries will be simpler with the string version. My general advice is to look at the queries you will be making and optimise the data import and schema for that – don't worry if your imports are complex if it makes your queries simple. I had forgot how limited SQLite's date functions were and for almost all cases you are probably best off with dates as strings.